# Book for molecular biology comparative to major taxonomic groups

Tags: evolution, molecular-biology, cell-biology, taxonomy, book-recommendation

Want recommendation of books on molecular biology (or molecular cell biology), that elaborately **compares** the  structures and phenomena in the major **taxonomic group**s.

**For say, whenever studying about a phenomenon** ( *may it be a structure like ribosome or nuclear DNA or plasmid or small RNA or nuclease enzymes, or may be phenomena like central dogma (replication, transcription, translation) or recombination or cell-division and its regulation, or may be protein folding or protein degradation, or biosignaling pathways*)... I could get the analyses about **in detail the similarities and the differences of the processes in different taxonomic groups.**  Such as, How does that process happen in prokaryotes (both archaea and eubacteria) and eukaryotes? Or if further zoom-in; how the process varies in major group of archaea, bacteria(Gram-positive and Gram negative), protists, animals (invertebrates and vertebrates),  plants(bryophytes, pteridophytes, gymnosperms, angiosperms), or fungi (glomeromycetes,ascomycetes, basidiomycetes etc)? or how the processes takes place in the mitochondrial and plastidial genomes of the different groups of organisms?

Best if the book could provide ample amount of data tables.

There are books and articles specific to a few certain taxonomic groups; but I'm looking for the big picture or the bird's eye view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt you'll find one. It would be a huge amount of work, it would be out of date immediately, and only three people would buy it. The days of printed catalogues of this type are long gone. The cheap updatable internet put an end to them. Even the "Where to Ski" book has sadly gone online.